# exp function to an arbitrary double precision

Tags: code-golf, math

Write a function to find the solution of [e^x](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exp%28x%29) given x, and a precision in the form 0.000001.

sample input and output:
`e(4,0.00001)` will return `54.5981494762146`, and the precision is +/- `.00001`. The output would be acceptable in the range `54.59814 <= output <= 54.59816`, you are not required to truncate the answer to the number of significant figures in the input precision.

Your example will be expected to take a precision of at least size `double` (64 bits) and an x of at least size `int` (32 bits). Overflows will not be counted against you; I do not expect passing INT_MAX as x to work.

Use whatever algorithm suits you, but do not use math library functions such as builtin `pow`, `factorial`, `exp`, or builtin predefined constants for `e`, `pi`, etc.

The objective primary winning criterion is size of submission in bytes, ignoring comments and unnecessary whitespace.

Ties will be broken via runtime speed.

This will last at least one week (ending Thursday, May 16) with each new entry extending the deadline to three days from the entry date.

Comment: Is there a limit to the precision?

Comment: What is the [objective primary winning criterion](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)?

Comment: Is this for all possible values of x or are there limits?

Comment: Surely with your example input, 54.59814999 would be a valid output?

Comment: `exp(4,.00001)` is nowhere near 54.

Comment: I have updated the question to address all of these concerns.

Comment: @KeithRandall [yes it is](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exp%284%29)

Comment: What are math libraries? Some languages have `exp` built in.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn that's what I was specifying should be disallowed. You need to write your own `exp`, `pow`, and `factorial` if you're going to use them in your algorithm.

Comment: What about the use of predefined constants (like `e` in this case). Some languages (esp. Math languages) have this number build-in.

Comment: Yet another good point. The spirit of this challenge is to come up with a novel way of calculating `e`, not simply counting digits and spitting it out.

Comment: @Greg: I was confused by your notation: by `exp(4,.00001)` you mean `e^4` with a tolerance of `.00001`, not `4^.00001`.

Comment: @KeithRandall Yep, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Does negative numbers have to work?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn For this case lets ignore negative input since so many answers would fail given negative numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### APL (36)

```
{x t←⍺⍵⋄0{t>i←(x*⍵)÷!⍵:⍺⋄∇/⍺⍵+i 1}0}
```

The left argument is the number and the right argument is the tolerance, i.e.

```
      4 {x t←⍺⍵⋄0{t>i←(x*⍵)÷!⍵:⍺⋄∇/⍺⍵+i 1}0}  0.00001
54.59814722
```

It uses a power series expansion.

Explanation:

- `x t←⍺⍵`: store the left argument (x) in `x` and the right argument (tolerance) in `t`
- `0{`...`}0`: iterator function, `⍺` is the accumulator and `⍵` is the iteration
- `t>i←(x*⍵)÷!⍵`: calculate the current iteration's value, and see if it is higher than the tolerance
- `:⍺`: if so, return the accumulator
- `⋄∇/⍺⍵+i 1`: if not, increment the accumulator by `i` and the iteration by `1` and try again.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 90

```
f[x_,p_]:=Piecewise[{{Sum[x^i/i!,{i,0,50}],x>0},{1/Sum[(-x)^i/i!,{i,0,50}],x<0},{1,x==0}}]
```

I also ignore the precision `p` and assume that 20 decimal points will be the most accuracy desired. It also works for negative values of `x`! To be worked on more later.

## Python, 88

```
def E(x,p):
 t=n=s=1.;y=x
 if x<0:y=-x
 while t:t*=y/n;n+=1;s+=t
 if x<0:s=1/s
 return s
```

**Why the Power Series approach does not work without cases:**

The issue with the taylor series for `e(x)` centered at the origin is that it is alternating for negative `x`. When the distance from the origin is small, say `x= -1 or -2` then this is not an issue as we get convergence to 20 decimal places after about 20-30 terms of the power series. However when the distance from the origin grows all hell breaks loose. Observe the pattern for `x= -1` where `f[x,n]` refers to the taylor series with `n+1` terms.

```
Exp[-20] = 2.0611536224385578280*10^-9
f[-20,1] = -19.000000000000000000
f[-20,2] = 181.00000000000000000
f[-20,3] = -1152.3333333333333333
f[-20,4] = 5514.3333333333333333
...
f[-20,10] = 1.8596236807760141093*10^6
f[-20,15] = -1.4140053694562736891*10^7
f[-20,20] = 2.1277210342544299144*10^7
f[-20,30] = 1.5996940964229284082*10^6
f[-20,40] = 4442.0343631250907290
f[-20,50] = 1.0469169720658217252
f[-20,60] = 0.000034317328370370852087
f[-20,70] = 2.2782871646157681977*10^-9
```

It takes until term 70 to get within .000000001 of the true value, and I was being kind using `x= -20`. If we try numbers as low as `x= -500` we are more than `10^200` off at term 500. Now lets see, what are we even working with at this point, iteration 500, this should include the term `x^500/500!`. `500!` if of the order `10^1134`, but python and other programming languages are not equipped to deal with numbers much larger than `2^63` as integers or `10^308` for doubles (unless you have some sort of arbitrary precision library...?)

Comment: Great explanation on negative x.

Answer (score 1):

### Python, <strike>59</strike> 57 chars

```
def E(x,p):
 t=n=s=1.
 while t:t*=x/n;n+=1;s+=t
 return s
```

Uses the power series expansion of `e^x`.  Ignores `p` and just calculates the result to full double precision.

Comment: You may save to chars with the initialisation if you reorder `while t:t*=x/n;n+=1;s+=t`.

Answer (score 0):

### C, <s>88</s> 69

```
double e(int e, double l) {double a,p=1,i=0,f=1,r=1;while ((a=(p*=e)/(f*=++i))>l) r+=a;return r;}
```

```
double e(int x, double l) {double i=0,t=1,r=1;while (t*=x/++i) r+=t;return r;}
```

call `e`. if you change the first argument to `e` from `int` to `double`, it will even work for floating point exponents.

Code counted without any white space or comments.

Edited some ideas from Keith into it (combine `p` and `f` into `t`, ignore `l`).

Yes, power series is the way to go. Sure, once one got the idea, everyone copy it.

Comment: Example: [Idone](http://ideone.com/h0MiHz). I don't know why there is a runtime error, maybe someone can enlighten me.

Comment: Missing `return 0`. http://ideone.com/dvHlO1

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript, 50 Chars**

Given that javascript has variable args support, this will work with the input `e(4,0.00001)`. Otherwise, it would be 52 chars.

```
function e(x){for(t=n=s=1;t*=x/n++;s+=t);return s}
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/XbRVJ0)

If it is going to factor in the precision as the problem states, it can be done in 56 chars.

```
function e(x,p){for(t=n=s=1;(t*=x/n++)>p;s+=t);return s}
```